# .NET Core 2.0 app on Linux with supervisor cannot run due to ArgumentNullException

Tags: asp.net, .net, linux, asp.net-core, supervisord

I have a .NET Core 2.0 application which I want to run on a Linux server.

Everything is set up correctly and if I run `dotnet MyApplication.dll` manually then the application starts and going to the url in the browser works fine.

I want to automatically start the application with `supervisor` as I have seen others do online.

Supervisor is installed and configured to run my application however the .NET app cannot start and I can see the errors in the `supervisor` error log.

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: path1
   at System.IO.Path.Combine(String path1, String path2)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer.CliFallbackFolderPathCalculator.get_DotnetUserProfileFolderPath()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer.FirstTimeUseNoticeSentinel..ctor(CliFallbackFolderPathCalculator cliFallbackFolderPathCalculator)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.ProcessArgs(String[] args, ITelemetry telemetryClient)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

`supervisor` configuration as follows:

```
[program:myapplication]
command=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/www/myapplication.mydomain/MyApplication.dll 
directory=/var/www/myapplication.mydomain
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/websites/myapplication.mydomain.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/websites/myapplication.mydomain.out.log
environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
user=myuser
stopsignal=INT
```

`dotnet --info` as follows:

```
.NET Command Line Tools (2.0.0)

Product Information:
 Version:            2.0.0
 Commit SHA-1 hash:  cdcd1928c9

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     ubuntu
 OS Version:  16.04
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         ubuntu.16.04-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.0.0/

Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host

  Version  : 2.0.0
  Build    : e8b8861ac7faf042c87a5c2f9f2d04c98b69f28d
```

Would love to get this working!

Also posted this issue on GitHub [here](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/1037)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found out that the fix for this was to set the supervisor configuration to the following:

```
command=/usr/bin/dotnet MyApplication.dll 
directory=/var/www/myapplication.mydomain
```

I guess because directory is setting the current working directory the path to the dll was wrong

Comment: This will also happen if the dll filename in the command is wrong too, as Iv'e just found out :-)